# Qlik - Comma Seperated list to Array for Dimension

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a field that is stored as a string list of changing size. For Example,

```
7,5,6,4,2,3
```

I need to build an expression such that it creates an array which will become the dimension on the x axis for a bar chart

I have used

```
SubField(string_list, ',')
```

However, it produces only 1 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use SubField in a LOAD statement, if you want to use it without the field_no parameter and generate a record for each value.
Otherwise you would need to specify the field_no explicitly.

Best regards,
Tom

Comment: As an example; load subfield(String,',') as MemberOf,ID;
load * 
inline [
String,ID
'1,2,3,4,5,6,7',1
'1,2,3,4,5,6',2
'4,5,6',3
'1,2,3',4
'1,2,3,6',5
'1,4,5,6',6
];

Answer (score 0):

Qlik supports the Javascript too.

So, may be this will help shortly:

```
function GetItemFromList(list, n, sep) {
    //if (sep === undefined) { sep = ';';}
    sep = typeof sep !== 'undefined' ? sep : ',';
    return list.split(sep)[n-1];
}
```

And use it in Loading Script:

```
GetItemFromList('$(LongMonthNames)',12,';') //Dec
```